# Mongoose return an empty array when using find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using `mongoose` to get data from a `mongoDb` database with this code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var MG_forecast = mongoose.model('MG_forecast');
var MG_solarInfo = mongoose.model('MG_solarInfo');

router.get('/full_forecast', function(req, res, next) { 
  console.log("=---= full_forecast");

  var day = new Date().getDate();
  var month = new Date().getMonth()+1;
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();

  //recherche du champ forecast dans la collection MG_forecast
  MG_forecast.find({"consult_day" : day, "consult_month":month, "consult_year" : year},function(err, docs){
   if(err){
     console.log("=---= full_forecast page : erreur GET , error : "+ err);
     return next(err); 
   }
    console.log("=---= full_forecast page : success GET ");
    if (docs.length == 0){
      console.log("=---= docs is empty !");
    }
    else {

      console.log("=---= docs = " + docs);
    }
    res.json(docs);
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var MG_forecastSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  consult_date_ms : Number,
  consult_day : Number,
  consult_month : Number,
  consult_year : Number,
  forecast: [{
    date: String, // looking like yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+UTC
    temperature: Number
  }]
});

mongoose.model('MG_forecast', MG_forecastSchema);
```

Here is the document i want to retrieve (it's much longer)

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("5630c6a2a31b5cd02987c4a4"),
  "consult_date_ms":1446037154407,
  "consult_day":28,
  "consult_month":10,
  "consult_year":2015,
  "forecast":[
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T15:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T16:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T17:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T18:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T19:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T20:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T21:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T22:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-28T23:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T00:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T01:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T02:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T03:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T04:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T05:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T06:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T07:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T08:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T09:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T10:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T11:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T12:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T13:00:00+01",
      "temperature":17
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T14:00:00+01",
      "temperature":18
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T15:00:00+01",
      "temperature":18
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T16:00:00+01",
      "temperature":18
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T17:00:00+01",
      "temperature":17
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T18:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T19:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T20:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T21:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T22:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-29T23:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T00:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T01:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T02:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T03:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T04:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T05:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T06:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T07:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T08:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T09:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T10:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T11:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T12:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T13:00:00+01",
      "temperature":17
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T14:00:00+01",
      "temperature":18
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T15:00:00+01",
      "temperature":18
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T16:00:00+01",
      "temperature":18
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T17:00:00+01",
      "temperature":17
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T18:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T19:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T20:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T21:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T22:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-30T23:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T00:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T01:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T02:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T03:00:00+01",
      "temperature":11
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T04:00:00+01",
      "temperature":11
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T05:00:00+01",
      "temperature":10
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T06:00:00+01",
      "temperature":9
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T07:00:00+01",
      "temperature":9
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T08:00:00+01",
      "temperature":10
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T09:00:00+01",
      "temperature":10
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T10:00:00+01",
      "temperature":11
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T11:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T12:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T13:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T14:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T15:00:00+01",
      "temperature":17
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T16:00:00+01",
      "temperature":17
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T17:00:00+01",
      "temperature":16
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T18:00:00+01",
      "temperature":15
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T19:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T20:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T21:00:00+01",
      "temperature":14
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T22:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-10-31T23:00:00+01",
      "temperature":13
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-11-01T00:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    },
    {
      "date":"2015-11-01T01:00:00+01",
      "temperature":12
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know why but all I got is an empty array, meanwhile there is something in my collection (I checked with the `mongoDB` shell) and the syntax seems correct.

Comment: Is there any chance you could edit your question using the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33395526/edit) link and include some sample data from the database?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Oh !  tried a lot of stuffs, changing my code several times I forgot to correct it ^^ I edited my post

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Regarding the 0 in the formatted date, i was pissed that i couln't find any solution the whole day, i didn't (and couldn't) think to everything ^^ but now you're telling me this i realise it.

Comment: @chridam It's done !

Comment: Try changing your `mongoose.model` call to: `mongoose.model('MG_forecast', MG_forecastSchema, 'MG_forecast');`

Comment: @JohnnyHK I tried this, but it's telling me that MG_forecastSchema is not defined (My Schema is in another file)

Comment: @Manouk I'm talking about making this change in that other file where you define the schema and register the model.

Comment: @JohnnyHK YEAAAAAAHHH !!! It works ! As Dr Frankenstein would say : " It's alive! It's alive !" Thank you so much  :D